# Onclick Javascript on custom button

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have created one custom button on detail page of my object. And written onclick javascript functionality to open page layout of its child record type which is based on TYPE picklist field on my object detail page.

For e.g If I select 'vehicle' from TYPE picklist field then on click of that button page layout of 'vehicle' record type of it's child should open.